# Spring Data repository proxy Pointcut on Annotation

Tags: aop, aspectj, spring-data

I know generally you cannot execute a pointcut based on an annotation that was made on an interface, but is there anyway to do this with Spring Data Repository Proxies?

I have custom annotations for caching and make use of AOP to intercept certain methods and cache values, very similar to how Ehcache works.

Is there any way to use these annotations with a Spring Data Repository?